# Finding the invertibility of a matrix (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A={a_{ij}}$ which is an  $n$x$n$ matrix. Prove the following statement or give a counter example if it is false. If $A$ is invertible, then

$$B =
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & ....a_{1,n-1} \\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2}& ....a_{2,n-1} \\
 a_{n-1,1}& a_{n-1,2} & ....a_{n-1,n-1}
\end{array} } \right]
$$

is also invertible.

What i tried.

matrix $B$ is matrix $A$ with the last row and the last column being removed. The above statement is false. While my conterexample is $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\1&1\\\end{bmatrix}$$ hence $B$ have to be the matrix $$B=[0]$$. Is my workings correct. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: yes that is a good conterexample!

Comment: You are good. That is enough right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct. You can actually generalise it to make a counterexample for an arbitrary $n\ge2$: consider $A=\pmatrix{I_{n-2}\\ &A_0}$ where $A_0=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&1}$.